# How to use IF ELSE Statement in SSRS Query Designer with parameter?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

What I am willing to achieve is:

1. Add a new Parameter to report called @OrderBy
2. If the value of the @OrderBy is null or blank then use the Order By DaysLate DESC (means the current functionality will be as it is)
3. If the value of @OrderBy is 1 then use Order By RugID ASC (means we will order the rugs by RugID in ascending order instead of days late descending order)

I used this query (screenshot below) to achieve it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(10) = 'Col1'
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)
INSERT @Tab VALUES
(1,2,3),
(3,2,1),
(4,5,6),
(7,8,9),
(8,7,6)

SELECT *
FROM @Tab
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Col1' THEN Col1
              WHEN @OrderBy = 'Col2' THEN Col2
              ELSE Col3 END
```

So in your situation it might look like:

```
... ORDER BY CASE WHEN COALESCE(@OrderBy,'') = '' THEN DaysLate DESC
                  WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN RugId
                  ELSE "Some Other Column" END
```

Having said that, it might be a better idea to specify the order logic in the report tablix group with an expression.